# Number of Groups returned by a query

Tags: sql, database

I am using an SQL query with of form

```
SELECT...FROM...WHERE...GROUP BY id
```

I want to know how many groups this query returns. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELECT count(id) FROM....WHERE...GROUP BY id

Answer (score 3):

@Tyler Ferraro answers should solve it.

In case the SQL query is very complicated, you can use a nested query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT...FROM...WHERE...GROUP BY id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
select count(*) from (Your SQL).